# ISS Repair/Maintenance Tools

Tags: iss, eva

Are the tools like the driver and the bolts on the ISS magnetized to prevent losing them when doing repair/maintenance? 
Is there a special way to prevent it other than magnets?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not magnetized, just good old fashioned tethers. All the tools have a place to connect a tether.  You can look at a catalog of all the EVA tools (it's kind of old, and a huge 750 page pdf) at this [link](https://archive.org/details/eva-tools-and-equipment-reference-book-nov-83-2).

For example, here's everyone's favorite tool, the hammer. Notice the tether point.

[image]

Comment: So what about bolts once they are removed they just try to hold them ?

Comment: If the device was designed for EVA repair, the bolts will be captive.  In other words, you can loose them but they are retained within the device.  This wasn't the case on some Hubble equipment and they just had to be careful.  Some examples here (search for "captive") https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&ved=0ahUKEwjfhqPWp8nPAhVBPD4KHZbaAEkQFgg7MAY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nasa.gov%2Fpdf%2F124114main_msg077.pdf&usg=AFQjCNH5Vep2pvZ7OYRm2v5KBdRI6HqLTQ&sig2=66bWsiy8qKTkEl54uc4gWA